# How to get horror movies from TMDB?

Tags: database, api, video

I could get popular, now playing movies from TMDB.
I wanna get the Horror movies.
If there are any API URL and solution, let me know, please

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list
```

I got popular movies like this

```
$popularMovies = Http::withToken(config('services.tmdb.token'))
->get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular')
->json()['results'];
```

Comment: did you happen to run into this URL: https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One can also try these steps**

To get list of **genres**-

`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list`

To get movies for a particular **genre**

`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/list/{GENRE_ID}`

**Ex** - `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/list/27`

since, **27** is the **genre id** for **Horror**

Answer (score 4):

Try using the API to search by genre (ID number).
 As you can see from the link below, Horror films are classed under **genre 27**:

https://www.themoviedb.org/genre/27-horror/movie

So maybe you can try:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/27/movie/horror
```

Or else:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=XXXXX&with_genres=27
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I added code of how to get popular movies
How can I use the API you shared me

Comment: What happens when you replace `popular` with `horror`?

Comment: I got nothing. 
https://www.themoviedb.org/genre/27-horror/movie
This is correct but how can I get these movies through API. :)

Comment: If this does not work, then you have serious problems. Use a `GET` request ... `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=YourNumber&with_genres=27` ...

Comment: Ok, let me try once more and will let you know, thanks

Comment: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=XXXXX&with_genres=27

I can use this. It works perfectly
GREAT

Comment: Now, I am getting only 20 films, How can I do to get more movies?

Comment: @LiQiang sorry for late reply. You can try adding `&page=2` or `&page=3` etc to see more results. They choose not to show all results by design, so you must make multiple queries. From [the admins](https://www.themoviedb.org/talk/587bea71c3a36846c300ff73#last) of TMDB.com.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=&language=en-US&query=horror&page=1&include_adult=false